# Wordpress 500 Internal Server Error with PHP pages in wp-content

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have several plugins that are shooting out 404 page not found errors when trying to load a page in the plugins directory.

For instance:
/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php

When I go to that link, I'll get a 404 page not found error. If I go to a link for a file in the plugins directory, it will load up just fine, i.e. /wp-content/plugins/test/test.jpg

What could be keeping php files from loading? My htaccess is the default. I've tried disabling all plugins. Site works fine in my local development environment, but not on my new GoDaddy dedicated hosting environment. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Any caching plugins you're having?

Answer (score 0):

First off rename .htaccess to .htaccess.txt as for security it doesn't allow direct access if that doesn't work check the path again

Comment: I tried that with no success. I am now getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to open PHP files in the wp-content directory. Any thoughts?

Comment: Rename the htaccess bk I'm going to do some testing on on this as iv never had this issue and iv written about 200 extensions